# Woocommerce Update Cart Hook

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have modified the table used in Woocommerce cart using jquery. This modification us called at the hook - woocommerce_before_cart

When I change the quantity and click "Update Cart", my jquery modifications are removed. Which hook shall i use to make the update cart button show my jquery table modification? Or is there a mistake that I am making? I am just totally lost.

Here is the action that I used -

```
 add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'random_function_goes_here');
```

To see the website with the problem check this link - http://www.nectarmodulars.com/cart/

Comment: Hello, I have see this is working. which thing you need to work ?

Comment: You have to first add some item to cart. Then change quantity, click update cart. Images inside "Laminate" and "Inner Design" columns will disappear.